# Bootstrap container is going over the page view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

As I am not a fan of CSS decided to use Bootstrap to my little project. However, one of the container is going over page view and I cannot understand why.

```html
<!-- STYLE -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar bg-primary">
  <div class="container text-white justify-content-center">
    <h1>Weather Dashboard</h1>
  </div>
</nav>

<main class="">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 bg-secondary">
      <!-- SIDE BAR ?-->
      <div class="row">
        <!-- side bar first row -->
        <div class="container">
          <h4>Search for a City:</h4>
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city-name-search" placeholder="Enter city name...">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <!-- side bar second row -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
          two
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bg-danger col-9">
      <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="container-fluid lh-1 border border-dark">
          <h2>City name (dd/mm/yyy)</h2>
          <p>Temp:</p>
          <p>Wind:</p>
          <p>Humidity:</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <h3>5-Day Forecast</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</main>

<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Picture of what I exactly mean:

[image]

Tried setting different margin and padding still without result I want. I can't find my answer in google either.

Additional question, why btn-block doesn't work? I had to use w-100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bootstrap, rows belong within containers:

> Containers are the most basic layout element in Bootstrap and are
> **required when using our default grid system**.

```html
<!-- STYLE -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar bg-primary">
  <div class="container text-white justify-content-center">
    <h1>Weather Dashboard</h1>
  </div>
</nav>

<main class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 bg-secondary">
      <!-- SIDE BAR ?-->
      <div class="row">
        <!-- side bar first row -->
        <div class="container">
          <h4>Search for a City:</h4>
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city-name-search" placeholder="Enter city name...">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <!-- side bar second row -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
          two
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bg-danger col-9">
      <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="container-fluid lh-1 border border-dark">
          <h2>City name (dd/mm/yyy)</h2>
          <p>Temp:</p>
          <p>Wind:</p>
          <p>Humidity:</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <h3>5-Day Forecast</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</main>

<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```